# Explanation of Magento 1.9.3 __call Change

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, ce-1.9.3.0, uploader

The changelog for Magento 1.9.3 mentions the following backwards-incompatible change:

> Mage_Uploader_Model_Config_Abstract: Overrides the magic method __call and its behavior can be inconsistent.

**Can somebody explain what this means?** The example cited in the changelog is not clear either. Is it saying the behavior was changed *to be* inconsistent or it was changed to *no longer be* inconsistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the Magento classes extend `Varien_Object` which implements the magic getter/setter/unsetter/has with the following `__call` method:

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('GETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('SETTER: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('UNS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            //Varien_Profiler::start('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            $key = $this->_underscore(substr($method,3));
            //Varien_Profiler::stop('HAS: '.get_class($this).'::'.$method);
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

Thus, we you call `getSomething`, `setSomething`, `hasSomething` or `unsSomething`, this method uses the data to return something (via `getData`, `setData` and `unsetData`.

In 1.9.3, `Mage_Uploader_Model_Config_Abstract` overrides this method :

```
public function __call($method, $args)
{
    $key = lcfirst($this->_camelize(substr($method,3)));
    switch (substr($method, 0, 3)) {
        case 'get' :
            $data = $this->getData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            return $data;

        case 'set' :
            $result = $this->setData($key, isset($args[0]) ? $args[0] : null);
            return $result;

        case 'uns' :
            $result = $this->unsetData($key);
            return $result;

        case 'has' :
            return isset($this->_data[$key]);
    }
    throw new Varien_Exception("Invalid method ".get_class($this)."::".$method."(".print_r($args,1).")");
}
```

The difference is that the key is not generated the same way.

Thus if you call `getMyDescription()` you will get the following:

- With `Varien_Object` : it will try to get the data with key = `my_description`
- With `Mage_Uploader_Model_Config_Abstract` : it will try to get the data with key = `myDescription`

To summarize, the result of the `__call` method is not consistent with every other Magento classes, the only other exception I'm aware of is `Mage_Paypal_Model_Payflow_Request`